# Not sure where I went wrong. Bindings not working

Tags: checkbox, knockout.js, binding

This is my first attempt using Knockout. I have read the tutorials but I am just getting it wrong

- I have static values for days of the week
- For each of these days, a time range/period is to be selectd (e.g from 0800 to 1700) - textfields
- For each of these days there is a checkbox that includes or excludes that date. If unchecked, that row is <s>deselected</s> disabled

So it is a table consisting of rows with

Day | From Time | To Time | Selected

My attempt:

ViewModel

```
//Generic class that will be contain each row item
var BusinessHourItem = function (day, fromTime,toTime, enabled) {
    var self = this;
    self.day = day;
    self.fromTime = ko.observable(fromTime);
    self.toTime = ko.observable(toTime);
    self.enabled = ko.observable(enabled);
}; 

//Actual View Model
var BusinessHoursViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    //Range Table
    self.dayTimeRangeTableItems = [
        new BusinessHourItem('MON', '00:00', '00:00', false),
        new BusinessHourItem('TUE', '00:00', '00:00', false),
        new BusinessHourItem('WED', '00:00', '00:00', false),
        new BusinessHourItem('THU', '00:00', '00:00', false),
        new BusinessHourItem('FRI', '00:00', '00:00', false),
        new BusinessHourItem('SAT', '00:00', '00:00', false),
        new BusinessHourItem('SUN', '00:00', '00:00', false)
    ];

    self.selectedItems = ko.observableArray();

    self.selectedItemsDelimited = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        return self.selectedItems().join(",");
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new BusinessHoursViewModel());
```

HTML

```
<h2>Selected Business Hours(<span data-bind="text: dateRangeDetails()"></span>)</h2>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Day</th><th>From</th><th>To</th><th>Select</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: dayTimeRangeTableItems">
        <tr>
            <td><input data-bind="value: day" /></td>
            <td><input data-bind="value: fromTime" /></td>
            <td><input data-bind="value: toTime" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="atrr: {value: $data}, checked: $parent.selectedItems" /></td>
        </tr>    
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dateRangeDetails function doesn't exist, but if you want use an object has ur checked value you can use the CheckedValue binding.

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: $data, checked: $parent.selectedItems" />
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/RapTorS/rwefL/

Comment: Thanks RaptorS. I prefer yours as you didnt alter much of my code.

Comment: Sorry, on the last point I meant disable the input elements when the corresponding row is unchecked.

Comment: I update the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/RapTorS/rwefL/4/
checkbox are bind to enabled observables and selectedItemsDelimited do filter on them.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably bind the checkbox value to the `enabled` property of the day of the `BusinessHourItem` object and then change the `selectedItems` from being an observable array to being a computed observable like the following:

```
self.selectedItems = ko.computed(function(){
    return self.dayTimeRangeTableItems.filter(function(item){
        return item.enabled();
    });
});
```

You have also bound the h2 to a property called `dateRangeDetails` which doesn't exist. I guess this is just a mistake in making the sample available here and that it should be bound to `selectedItemsDelimited`. The `selectedItemsDelimited` should, by the way, probably get the names of the days, or some other string representation of the objects, to ensure it's not displayed as `[object, object]` or similar.

I have created a fiddle using your code and making the small changes necessary to get it working which you find at http://jsfiddle.net/tR9HH/.